# How do I import video and screen recording from iPhone to the Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, video

Is it by using the Photos app on the Mac?  I had a 35 minute screen recording on the iPhone and then selected 4 minutes from it, and created a new video. On the iPhone I can see this new video in the Photo Album, but on Photos app on the Mac, I only see the 35 minute one, but not the 4 minute one.

Are there other ways to transfer it to the Mac?

One way is to upload to YouTube from my iPhone and then download from YouTube using some YouTube video downloader plugin, but that's kind of a silly way.

If it matters, the screen recording was done using iOS 11 public beta 2.

Comment: By what mechanism do the libraries sync? (i.e. how did the 35 minute one sync and could you perhaps just be waiting for the rest due to daily caps or just delay?)

Comment: using the Photos app on the Mac -- what mechanism is that? Daily cap? Is there a daily cap for transferring things from my iPhone to my Mac?

Comment: iCloud - yes - there are caps and throttles and potential delays. If you're not syncing through iCloud - then you can ignore that part of the comment